# Install yEnc - Python

Tags: python, pip, decode, encode, crc32

**I am trying to install yenc using pip in Linux**

```
pip install yenc
```

However I received the error below
[image: Error: Failed building wheel for yenc]

Same with pip3

```
pip3 install yenc
```

I tried multiple suggested online solutions **but no luck** (Shown below)

```
sudo apt-get update
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade pip
pip3 install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxmlsec1-dev
pip install p5py
pip3 install p5py
pip install PEP517
pip3 install PEP517
pip3 install yenc
sudo apt-get install -y pkg-config
sudo apt-get install libsuitesparse-dev
```

My current pip version

```
pip --version
pip 23.2.1
```

My current python version

```
python3 --version
Python 3.10.4
```

---

```
                               **Follow Up**
```

As suggested I installed yenc on Python2,7 using pip2.7

```
pip2.7 install yenc
```

**Installation succeeded**

```
Successfully installed yenc-0.4.0
```

I run the script and got the following error

```
ERROR: Loading module scapy.layers.ipsec
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/main.py", line 156, in _load
mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/layers/ipsec.py", line 163, in <module>
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import (
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/aead.py", line 10, in <module>
from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl import aead
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 16, in <module>
from cryptography import utils, x509
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/x509/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
from cryptography.x509 import certificate_transparency
ImportError: cannot import name certificate_transparency
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "yenc.py", line 5, in <module>
import yenc 
  File "/home/kali/Documents/HidenInPlain/yenc.py", line 12, in <module>
decoded = yenc.decode("./data","./result")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Following online documentation, I'm sure that decode is an actual attribute of yenc, unlike what the error suggest.

References:

[ICMP yenc](https://cheatsheet.haax.fr/network/icmp/)
[yenc decode](https://blog.stalkr.net/2010/05/defcon-18-ctf-quals-writeup-packet-100.html)

Here is the Python script:

```
# Using Python
#!/usr/bin/python

from scapy.all import *
import yenc 

pkts = rdpcap("./merge.pcap")
file = open("./data","w")

for i in range(0,len(pkts)):
    file.write(pkts[i].load)
    deco = yenc.decode("./data","./result")
```

---

```
                        Follow Up
```

I tried renaming my script (yenc.py) to another name, I got a different error this time

```
ERROR: Loading module scapy.layers.ipsec
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/main.py", line 156, in _load
mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/layers/ipsec.py", line 163, in <module>
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import (
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/aead.py", line 10, in <module>
from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl import aead
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 16, in <module>
from cryptography import utils, x509
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/x509/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
from cryptography.x509 import certificate_transparency
ImportError: cannot import name certificate_transparency
```

Comment: Please post the full error message. Use the [edit] function and copy-paste the complete output you get from `pip install`. Don't make screenshots of text

Comment: `yenc` 0.4.0  Released: Sep 6, 2011. https://pypi.org/project/yenc/ Provides wheels only for Python 2.7. Declares compatibility with Python 2.5, 2.6 and 2.7 I am absolutely sure it cannot work with Python 3. The homepage repository is absent. Seems like an outdated abandoned project, not worth trying.

Comment: @phd Now that you mentioned it I just tried installing it using "pip2.7 install yenc", installation was successful. However I run the code and got "module object has no attribute decode"

Comment: No idea, never seen the module before. Perhaps in addition to being outdated and abandoned it's also buggy. The bug could be reported in an issue tracker but its repository long gone. Please [edit] the question and add the text of the full traceback, may be the problem is not that big.

Comment: rename your script from `yenc.py` to something different

Comment: @phd, hopefully this can be fixed, even though its an outdated project, unfortunately  I'm in a situation that enforces me to use yEnc.

Comment: "*As suggested I installed yenc on Python2,7*" I'm not sure if a comment was deleted or something, but I'm not quite sure how you reached the conclusion that others have suggested you install a version of Python that's been end-of-life since January 2020 (>3.5 years ago) and hasn't received anything in the way of security patches, etc. since. A better, more sustainable idea would be to re-evaluate the requirement you're attempting to implement using this outdated package and finding more modern alternatives to do so.

Comment: I tried renaming the script, I got a different error this time

Comment: The 3rd error has nothing with `yenc` it's from `cryptography` imported from `scapy`.